# Napa SharePoint app not finding the created sharepoint list

Tags: office365-apps

Using free office365 account, default sharepoint online website was created. On it I created a list called "Product".  When I try to get all the websites lists, the Product list is not listed. Only 2 lists **(1) Composed looks & (2) Master page gallery** are getting listed.  Below is the my App.js code;

```
'use strict';

var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
var web =  context.get_web();
var lists = context.get_web().get_lists();
var listItems;

(function () {

// This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is 
// needed to use the SharePoint object model
$(document).ready(function () {
    getAllLists();
});

// This function prepares, loads, and then executes a SharePoint query to get 
// the current users information
function getAllLists() {
    context.load(lists);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetListsSuccess, onGetListsFail);

}

// This function is executed if the above call is successful
// It replaces the contents of the 'message' element with the user name
function onGetListsSuccess() {
    $('#message').text('Hello ' + lists.get_count().toString());
    //$('#message').text('Hello ' + web.get_title().toString());

 var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
 var selectListBox = document.getElementById("ListItemListBox");


 if (selectListBox.hasChildNodes()) {
     while (selectListBox.childNodes.length >= 1) {
         selectListBox.removeChild(selectListBox.firstChild);
     }
 }
// Traverse the elements of the collection, and load the name of
// each list into the dropdown list box.
 while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
     var selectOption = document.createElement("option");
     selectOption.value = listEnumerator.get_current().get_title();
     selectOption.innerText = listEnumerator.get_current().get_title();
     selectListBox.appendChild(selectOption);
 }

}

// This function is executed if the above call fails
function onGetListsFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get user name. Error:' + args.get_message());
}


})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please firstly realize some concepts about sharepoint app :

**App Web - Site on which the App is deployed**

You would require the App to access and to use the SharePoint components such as the lists, content types, workflows, and pages. In this Case, all your SharePoint components should be deployed in a separate SharePoint site, called as the App Web.

**Host Web - Site on which the App is installed**

The actual site where the app is deployed is called the Host Web.

From your code ,you get to the App Web through the clientcontext.get_current( ) method which returns the current context that the user is running in .So you will see only two lists in your listbox .If you want to access information in the Host Web, a different approach is required. You could use an object called the AppSiteContext ,code below is for your reference:

```
'use strict';
var web;
var hostcontext;
var lists;
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var  currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentcontext, hostUrl);
    web = hostcontext.get_web();
    lists = web.get_lists();
    getAllLists();
});

function getAllLists() {
    context.load(lists);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetListsSuccess, onGetListsFail);
}

// This function is executed if the above call is successful
// It replaces the contents of the 'message' element with the user name
function onGetListsSuccess() {
    $('#message').text('Hello ' + lists.get_count().toString());
    var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
    // Traverse the elements of the collection, and load the name of
    // each list into the dropdown list box.
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        alert(listEnumerator.get_current().get_title());
  }
}

//this is just the sample function that's in all the MS samples

function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params =
    document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
  }
}

// This function is executed if the above call fails
function onGetListsFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get user name. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```